# Does Dojo framework support grouping/bunching of same type of commands to avoid multiple request to server?

Tags: dojo

I know, we can do grouping of same kind of Ajax requests to server.

But just wanted to know if Dojo supports this or let us know if this feature doesn't depend upon Dojo framework or jquery...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of request you do, and how response headers are set, some kinds of AJAX requests can be cached by the browser itself, just like it would cache a normal webpage.

Outside of the browser caching stuff, I don't know of any framework that does caching at the request level like that. So, if you need a request to not be repeated the only way to be sure is to not issue the request in the first place.

In Dojo's case, for example, it is quite common to issue AJAX requests via something like dojo/store/JsonRest instead of doing them by hand. In this case it is quite easy to use something like a dojo/store/Cache to add a cacheing layer in front of the JsonRest store.

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/store/Cache
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/02/15/dojo-object-stores/